# Can I use the name of a ministry that no longer exists in my novel inspired by true events?

Tags: novel

I'm writing a novel inspired by true events. The ministry I'm writing about shut down several years ago and no longer exists. Can I use that ministry by name without legal repercussions?

Comment: Laws are not the same all over the world. **If you want legal advice, you need to ask a lawyer.** You've given us no other clues to help, like where you live, where you will publish, the name/function of this (government?) 'ministry', whether you are defaming them in your story....

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'most likely' if you live in a country where Freedom of Expression has legal protections. Generally speaking, writers are never sued over their writings. Publishers get sued. Of course, if you don't live in a free country, then writers and publishers get jailed and murdered quite often.

Assuming you live in a liberal society, write what you want to write, the way you want to write, then let the publisher worry about legal repercussions. If you come up with a great story and the name of the ministry is a problem the publisher will ask you to change it. Publishers have lawyers and lots of experience dealing with 'legal repercussions.'

If you instead to self-publish, then legal repercussions are your responsibility. And, you'll have to manage them in every country you chose to publish in. This is when you need to work with lawyers to understand your exposure since the laws are different where ever you go.